# Header overlaps button

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I am trying to implement a cross platform mobile app via apache cordova on VS 2015. The problem is the header overlaps the button somehow. I checked the CSS files and js file but couldn't manage to resolve. Any clues?

Here is my sample index file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="connect-src 'self' https://ip/wcf/OCRService.svc 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'; default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">

    <title>LoTTo</title>

    <!-- LoTTo references -->

    <link href="css/ionicons.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/ng-img-crop.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- Cordova reference, this is added to your app when it's built. -->

    <script src="scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/ng-img-crop.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="cordova.js"></script>-->
    <script src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/index.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="scripts/angular-ios9-uiwebview.patch.js"></script>-->
    <script src="scripts/ng-file-upload-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/ng-file-upload.min.js"></script>


    <style>
        .cropArea {
            background: #E4E4E4;
            overflow: hidden;
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body ng-app="starter">
    <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-header bar-light">
        <h1 class="title">LoTTo</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content ng-controller="ExampleController" padding="true">
        <button class="button button-full button-balanced icon-right ion-ios-camera" ng-click="takePhoto()">
            Resim Çek
        </button>

        <button class="button button-full button-balanced icon-right ion-images" ng-click="choosePhoto()">
            Resim Seç
        </button>
        <center>
            <div class="cropArea">

               <img-crop image="myImage" result-image="myCroppedImage" change-on-fly="false"
                          area-type="rectangle"
                          area-min-size="100"
                          result-image-format="image/jpeg"
                          result-image-quality="1"
                          result-image-size="300"></img-crop>
            </div>
            <div ng-show="myImage !== undefined">Gönderilecek Resim:</div>

            <div><img ng-src="{{myCroppedImage}}" ng-show="myImage !== undefined" id="image" /></div>

        </center>
        <button class="button button-full button-balanced icon-right ion-images" ng-click="upload(myCroppedImage)" ng-if="myImage !== undefined">
            Resim Yükle
        </button>


    </ion-content>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance & Best Regards.

Here is the ripple output:
[overlap image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKcRo.png)

Edit 1: If I uncomment the cordova.js from header, the button totally disappears.
Here is ripple output:
[disappear image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6bwH.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add margin below the h1 element

```
h1.title {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

This will add some more space before the buttons.

Comment: Hi @Richard Hamilton, I added your code into ionic.css but it doesn't work. Something is breaking it but I couldn't find. If I uncomment `-<script src="cordova.js"></script>` cordova in the header, the button totally goes under title.

Comment: I think it is due to this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27614857/ngimgcrop-dependency-injection-not-working-properly-in-angularjs). I will check and let you know.

Comment: Yes, it was due to ng-img-crop.js like I said in my previous post. Now everything looks OK!